# Javascript inside HTML not working in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have JavaScript for my navbar which I put inside the component which is to close and open the navbar. However, none of the functions work for javascript. Please help me how I can fix this to make it work.
I have tried script under html and also tried putting my javascript under assets. However, I do not know how to call that file from my navbar.component.ts file.

**sidebar.component.html:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidebar',
  templateUrl: './sidebar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidebar.component.css'],
})
export class SidebarComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    let arrow = document.querySelectorAll('.arrow');
    for (var i = 0; i < arrow.length; i++) {
      arrow[i].addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        let arrowParent = e.target.parentElement.parentElement;
        arrowParent.classList.toggle('showMenu');
      });
    }

    let sidebar = document.querySelector('.sidebar');
    let sidebarBtn = document.querySelector('.bx-menu');
    sidebarBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
      sidebar.classList.toggle('close');
    });
  }

  routeFunction(name: string) {
    this.router.navigate([name]);
  }
}
```

**My HTML:**

```
<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="logo-details">
    <i class="fas fa-institution"></i>
    <span class="logo_name">APP</span>
  </div>
  <ul class="nav-links">
    <li>
      <a (click)="routeFunction('Dashboard')">
        <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
        <span class="link_name">Dashboard</span>
      </a>
      <ul class="sub-menu blank">
        <li><a class="link_name" href="#">Home</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a (click)="routeFunction('add')">
        <i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i>
        <span class="link_name">Add Payment</span>
      </a>
      <ul class="sub-menu blank">
        <li><a class="link_name" href="#">Add Payment</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a (click)="routeFunction('view')">
        <i class="fa fa-user-cog"></i>
        <span class="link_name">View Purchases</span>
      </a>
      <ul class="sub-menu blank">
        <li><a class="link_name" href="#">Manage Students</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a (click)="routeFunction('delete')">
        <i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>
        <span class="link_name">Delete Payment</span>
      </a>
      <ul class="sub-menu blank">
        <li><a class="link_name" href="#">Delete Payment</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="profile-details">
        <div class="profile-content">
          <img src="profile.png" alt="profile" />
        </div>
        <div class="name-job">
          <div class="profile_name">Admin</div>
          <div class="job">Admin</div>
        </div>
        <i class="bx bx-log-out"></i>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<section class="home-section">
  <div class="home-content">
    <i class="bx bx-menu"></i>
    <span class="text"> Dashboard</span>
  </div>
</section>

<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ngAfterViewInit);
</script>
```

Comment: You can do this natively in angular with click event on your template any reason why you're not?

Comment: Angular is a javascript based framework, which means it would need to load the contents of the page, then build the template, render it, and only then, elements can be accessible. You'd need to start with `window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", myfunction)` and work your way from there adding a timeout (knowing that the timeout will change depending on the computer that runs your script) if you want to do it this way

Comment: I am new to angular and not really good with javascript either, therefore, I am not sure to how make it work

Answer (score 0):

You can provide this code inside **ngAfterViewInit** life cycle inside your navbar component

```js
ngAfterViewInit(){
  let arrow = document.querySelectorAll(".arrow");
  console.log(arrow);
  for (var i = 0; i < arrow.length; i++) {
    arrow[i].addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      let arrowParent = e.target.parentElement.parentElement;
      arrowParent.classList.toggle("showMenu");
    });
  }
}
    
let sidebar = document.querySelector(".sidebar");
let sidebarBtn = document.querySelector(".bx-menu");
sidebarBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  sidebar.classList.toggle("close");
});
```

make sure you implement **AfterViewInit** life cycle inside your navbar component class

```
export navbarComponent implements AfterViewInit
```

Comment: I included AfterViewInit as you recommended, however, on "e.target.parentElement" and "sidebarBtn.addEventListener", and 'sidebar.classList", it gives an error stating that ".. it is possibly null". I have tested my javascipt in another normal folder without angular and it works perfectly.

Comment: You have to make sure that these elements are loaded into the DOM before ngAfterviewInit run I don't know about the structure of your code but to make sure that everything is loaded please put all for your code inside an setTimeout with some test delay for example 100ms delay and then check if your code run successfully or not

Comment: Thank you for the reply Daniel. I added DOMContentLoad event under my HTML. I just updated this question with recent changes. I am new to angular, therefore, I am not sure about setTimeout function. I also added the sidebar.component.ts code in my questions, can you please take a look and assist me with this.